# How do I mock `BalanceOf` for testing staking?

Tags: balances, testing

I'm trying to learn how to use the staking pallet in a game I'm building as a way to learn substrate, [linked here](https://github.com/stonecharioteer/substrate-node-connect-four), and I'd like to implement staking an amount when challenging another player.
However, I'm using Frame 4.0.0-dev, and I'm unable to find enough resources to help me understand how to mock `BalanceOf` for writing tests.
Could someone point me to some?
I've been looking at [lockable currency](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/pallet-design/implement-lockable-currency/), but [that pallet](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-how-to-guides/tree/main/example-code/template-node/pallets/lockable-currency/src) doesn't have any tests.

Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you going to use the `BalanceOf`?

I think you could take a look at the [pallet-balances](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d1f905bad9/frame/balances).
It shows you:

- [how to define a `BalanceOf` type](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d1f905bad9/frame/balances/README.md)
- [how to implement the `LockableCurrency`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5a48536a49859f83dbbbab1285311f14c192e7b1/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L2115-L2182)
- [a lot of unit tests](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d1f905bad9/frame/balances/src/tests.rs)

Answer (score 1):

In your `mock.rs` file at the very end you are building the mock storage with `pub fn new_test_ext()`. In there, you can use `pallet_balances` to predefine some balances for your addresses along the lines of:

```
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    let mut t = frame_system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap();
    pallet_balances::GenesisConfig::<Test> {
        balances: vec![(1, 100_000), (2, 100_000), (3, 100_000), (4, 100_000), (5, 100_00)],
    }
    .assimilate_storage(&mut t)
    .unwrap();
    t.into()
}
```

Also add `Balances: pallet_balances` to `construct_runtime!` .